# Jboss 7.1.1 Final as Windows service

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Below link is showing 404 error
http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-10

Where can I download the jboss-native-2-0-10 for Jboss7.1.1 final as windows service?

Is there any other way for Jboss7.1.1 as Windows service without using the jboss-native-2-0-10? Kindly help with your suggestions, please.

Comment: StackOverflow  is for programming questions, not for locating something from the internet.

Comment: Is there any other way for Jboss7.1.1 as Windows service without using the jboss-native-2-0-10 ?